# boost::interprocess::interprocess_condition::timed_wait waits forever

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-synchronization, boost-interprocess

I've the following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_condition.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_mutex.hpp>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  boost::interprocess::interprocess_condition ic;
  boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex im;
  bool test = false;
  auto testFunction = [&ic, &im, &test]() {
    boost::unique_lock lk(im);
    auto tin = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    auto waitTime = tin + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100);
    if (!ic.timed_wait(lk, waitTime)) {
      test = false;
    }
    else {
      test = true;
    }
  };

  auto notifyFunction = [&ic]() {
    ic.notify_all();
  };

  boost::thread t(testFunction);
  boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
  boost::thread t2(notifyFunction);
  t.join();
  t2.join();
  std::cout << "Result is: " << std::boolalpha << test << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

What I was expecting is that inside the lambda function the interprocess_condition variable `ic` waits for 100 milliseconds, and then the function continues. Instead the condition waits for the notify called in second thread.

What I' doing wrong? How should I use in correct way `timed_wait` in order to wait the desired amount of time?

I'm using boost version 1.72.0.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I need to use `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time` rather than `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time`.